# How to type check a binary type alias in Typescript

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, language-features, type-alias

I would like to depend a condition on the given type of an argument, but since all possible arguments are the same binary type (number), I look for a way to create some kind of a type alias, that can be checked for.

This is the initial idea, that doesn't work, because typescript is compiled into javascript and thus `bonus` will always be the javascript type `number`.

```js
    type Percentage = number;

    class Foo {
      applyBonus(bonus: Percentage | number) {
        if (typeof bonus === 'Percentage') {
          console.log('Percent');
        } else {
          // it's always number, because at execution time we're in javascript land here
          console.log('number'); 
        } 
      }
    }

    let bar = new Foo();
    bar.applyBonus(5);
    bar.applyBonus(6 as Percentage);
```

This question is mainly focused on the possibilities of the typescript language, and if this can be solved with typescript features. It would be easily possible to use an object like `{value:6,type:'percent'}` instead of a binary type number.

Comment: Can't do it without runtime checks but you might find this library interesting: https://github.com/gcanti/money-ts.

Comment: TypeScript uses a [structural type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) which means that `number` and `Percentage` represent exactly the same things. Some languages use a [nominal type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) which would allow what you describe, but it is not possible in TypeScript to distinguish between two number (or any other structurally equivalent) types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript doesn't type based on the names of things, but the structure of thing. You can name a number something else, but it's still a number. `Percentage` here is just an alias.

A better way to do something like this would be to create an interface with a unique shape that you could easily identify at runtime.

```
interface Percentage { percentage: number }

class Foo {
   applyBonus(bonus: Percentage | number) {
      if (typeof bonus === 'object') {
         console.log('Percent', bonus.percentage);
      } else {
         console.log('number', bonus); 
      } 
   }
}

new Foo().applyBonus(123)
new Foo().applyBonus({ percentage: 456 })
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArSeOBzFBvZABwwi1wC5kQBXAWwCNpkBfAKFYQBs4BnH5AGIB7IcjytkkuIUKcAngCEhNHgAp6y6j0roomMDhQAfKnUZQAlGImTbwGMlVg5xIQ40rkAXh-IA5EL0AFYQCGB+VuK20ZIIyjxCnBAAdJxC2Kp+uvp+ADTIHlrJxHqkBrgWANw20czIEJw8+DUxyHEgCUmp6Zk0DNB5BZo8VcgtknU1bGysIBAA7oIiqhbJ0rKKw6oAjABMAMwWswtLQitrMvJKKqoEJfqGlHv7LBZAA)

---

Alternatively (I don't recommend this, but is interesting academically), you could subclass `Number` and use that.

```
class Percentage extends Number { }

class Foo {
   applyBonus(bonus: Percentage | number) {
      if (bonus instanceof Percentage) {
         console.log('Percent', bonus);
      } else {
         console.log('number', bonus); 
      } 
   }
}

new Foo().applyBonus(123)
new Foo().applyBonus(new Percentage(456))
```

---

But really, I would question your need for this. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here, but there is probably a simpler way.

Comment: Your second example is exactly what I was looking for. As I mentioned, I'm not looking for a production code solution rather than a "what's possible in TS" kind of thing for a talk I plan and this approach is perfect to also point out that there are things (risks) you should take into account with a transpiler language. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

## Code Example

```js
type Percentage = number;

    class Foo {
      applyBonus(bonus: Percentage | number) {
        if (typeof bonus === 'Percentage') {
          console.log('Percent');
        } else {
          // NO, IT IS NOT ALWAYS NUMBER BECAUSE OF THAT
          console.log('number'); 
        } 
      }
    }

    let bar = new Foo();
    bar.applyBonus(5);
    bar.applyBonus(6 as Percentage);
```

## Real Reason

#### JavaScript

**JavaScript** as well as any other programming language out there, comes with a set of primitive values. Which since `es6` are *Six*

- number
- string
- boolean
- undefined
- null
- symbol

As you could notice `Percentage` is not one of them.

something that could be right from your `execution time we're in javascript land here` statement is the fact the types "do not exists on JS" ... not quite true as types do exists in JS, but the compiled code from your example looks some like this

```js
class Foo {
    applyBonus(bonus) {
      if (typeof bonus === 'Percentage') {
        console.log('Percent');
      } else {
        console.log('number'); 
      } 
    }
  }

  let bar = new Foo();
  bar.applyBonus(5);
  bar.applyBonus(6);
```

if we look at the `bar.applyBonus` you are passing a *5* n *6* which are two primitive values as both of them are numbers

if you dont believe me open the console of the browser and paste this
`typeof 5`

[image]

and "Percentage" !== "number"

that is the reason why you always get inside the else. The only way  you can have an `instanceof` Percentage is by creating an Object call Percentage:

```js
class Percentage {
  constructor (value) {
     this.value = value;
  }
}

 class Foo {
      applyBonus(bonus) {
        if (bonus instanceof === Percentage) {
          console.log('Percent');
        } else {
          // NO, IT IS NOT ALWAYS NUMBER BECAUSE OF THAT
          console.log('number'); 
        } 
      }
    }

    let bar = new Foo();
    bar.applyBonus(5);
    bar.applyBonus(new Percentage(6));
```